# What is the limit of sending messages from a telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I would like to understand the limits that Telegram bot API is imposing on message sending.

I know that currantly you cannot send more than 30 messages to differant users.

I have many bots running on the same server (Webhooks & Pull Updates), does they affect each others limits ?

I also have a multi-tenant bot that you can register many bot accounts, and it will manage them all in the same way concurrently.

If I am sending messages using differant bot accounts (tokens) but from the same server does it limit me to 30 messages per host or per bot account ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

About rate limit, please see [this FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this), there already explained that.

Rate limit is based on bot account, so even you can create 20 bots to avoid hitting rate limit.

Comment: I have read that FAQ before, but can you lead me to where they said it is per account not per host ?

Comment: I have checked with telegram support and they confirmed that the limit is per bot account not per host.

Comment: @ZaidAl-Omari am i right, that one host (client, bound to phone) may have many bot accounts?

Answer (score 2):

20 message per minite to the same group,too slow.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#broadcasting-to-users

**Broadcasting to Users**

My bot is hitting limits, how do I avoid this?
When sending messages inside a particular chat, avoid sending more than one message per second. We may allow short bursts that go over this limit, but eventually you'll begin receiving 429 errors.

If you're sending bulk notifications to multiple users, the API will not allow more than 30 messages per second or so. Consider spreading out notifications over large intervals of 8—12 hours for best results.

Also note that your bot will not be able to send more than 20 messages per minute to the same group.

**How can I message all of my bot's subscribers at once?**

Unfortunately, at this moment we don't have methods for sending bulk messages, e.g. notifications. We may add something along these lines in the future.

In order to avoid hitting our limits when sending out mass notifications, consider spreading them over longer intervals, e.g. 8-12 hours. The API will not allow bulk notifications to more than ~30 users per second, if you go over that, you'll start getting 429 errors.

See also: How to avoid hitting limits?